# Jackson: InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, jackson

Pretty straightforward, according to the docs.

My POJO field looks like this:

```
public class Message {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date _timestamp;

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return _timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this._timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

I try to map it with Jackson like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Message message = mapper.readValue(message, Message.class);
```

The incoming date string looks like this:

```
2018-10-30 12:44:34.270
```

I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2018-10-30 12:44:34.270': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2018-10-30 12:44:34.270': Can not parse date "2018-10-30 12:44:34.270": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

I've tried the following but the error doesn't change:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

Not sure what else I can do. I can't change the incoming format so this is what I have to live with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the Date to LocalDateTime with @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")

Comment: @TridevChaudhary Results in: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime] from String value ('2018-10-30 13:13:16.988'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: (String)" <...entire JSON object listed here...> (through reference chain: com.me.model.Message["timestamp"])

Comment: You might have to write a custom de-serializer check this out https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With your `Message` class and JSON-input  `{ "_timestamp": "2018-10-30 12:44:34.270" }` it works fine for me.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch - I conducted the exact same test and can reproduce. I hard-coded a JSON string and removed all but the timestamp field from the POJO I'm mapping to. Same error:

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Message message = mapper.readValue("{\"timestamp\":\"2018-10-30 15:55:18.647\"}", Message.class);

Comment: You need to use `_timestamp`, not `timestamp`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch You nailed it! I changed all the variable names and things started lining up, including the date field. Thanks so much. You should get credit, so post the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you expected it to be:

The name `timestamp`in your JSON input

```
{ "timestamp": "2018-10-30 12:44:34.270" }
```

simply did not match the name `_timestamp` in your Java class `Message`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private Date _timestamp;
```

There are several alternative ways how to make it matching:

- In the JSON input change `"timestamp"` to `"_timestamp"`
- In the Java code change `Date _timestamp;` to `Date timestamp;`
  (and also change the code with your getter and setter accordingly)
- In the Java code add the annotation `@JsonProperty("timestamp")`
  to your `Date _timestamp;` definition

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would have been nice if the error hadn't been so misleading.